# Selenium javascript link

Tags: selenium

Could anyone please help me to hit the `javascript` link through selenium code.

This is the inspect code and link name is Applications.

Currently I am using below all the list of code, but still it's not hitting the applications link.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("I6")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@ src='/ibm/console/images/arrow_collapsed.gif']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Applications']")).click(); 
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),Applications')]"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click;", element);
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Applications']"));
element1.click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='javascript:expandCollapse('6');]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='I6']/..//a[contains(text(),'Applications')]")).click();
```

Comment: There's just nothing happens after you click it or you get an exception? Share logs if there any

Comment: please check the inspect code details

Comment: <img src="/ibm/console/images/arrow_expanded.gif" title="Collapse" alt="Collapse" id="I6" border="0" align="absmiddle">

<img src="/ibm/console/images/arrow_collapsed.gif" title="Expand" alt="Expand" id="I6" border="0" align="absmiddle">
<a style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" href="javascript:expandCollapse('6');" title="Applications"><img src="/ibm/console/images/arrow_collapsed.gif" title="Expand" alt="Expand" id="I6" border="0" align="absmiddle"><span dir="ltr">Applications</span></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to click `WebElement` using `javascript` this way.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Applications']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

I have try with your this `html` code:

```
<img src="/ibm/console/images/arrow_expanded.gif" title="Collapse" alt="Collapse" id="I6" border="0" align="absmiddle"> <img src="/ibm/console/images/arrow_collapsed.gif" title="Expand" alt="Expand" id="I6" border="0" align="absmiddle"> <a style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" href="javascript:expandCollapse('6');" title="Applications"><img src="/ibm/console/images/arrow_collapsed.gif" title="Expand" alt="Expand" id="I6" border="0" align="absmiddle"><span dir="ltr">Applications</span></a>
```

Refer Image for more details:

[image]

Comment: Yes @Jainish, i tried but still not reflecting or clicking the link

Comment: not possible , it's business URL for websphere deployment . you are not authorized person to hit the url.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, there is typo in all of your `xpath` like :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Applications']")).click();  \\missed `)` in contains method
```

If see carefully somewhere `'` missing  and somewhere `()` , Ok leave it, try the following `xpath` and let us know still face same issue

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Applications']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Applications')]")).click();
```